# How to clear a cell based on hours old, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, windows, time

I am trying to clear the contents of a cell within Microsoft Excel 2016 on one sheet when its age is over 8 hours. We review all incoming work after 8 hours and allocate additional resources if required.

I have 3 sheets Test, VLOOKUP and Log. Test is the only one visible to the general user, VLOOKUP holds the Vlookup tables to work out age, Log is exactly that, a log of all changes made.

Through the use of a a circular equation I have been able to output the time when a cell is altered, this is put into the VLOOKUP sheet -

=IF(Test!E6<>"",IF(K4="",NOW(),K4),"")

Within the VLOOKUP sheet, I have a cell that shows NOW (H3).

I want to be able to use the data from the VLOOKUP, K column, to feed the clear contents of the Test E:G columns, 1 row at a time and only if the K cell is over 8 hours old.

I have tried a number of options but, have not been able to clear another sheet based on VLOOKUP sheet values.

This is my current working -

```
Sub DeleteRowsBeforeCutoff()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Worksheets("VLOOKUP").Range(K3) < DateAdd("h", -8, Now) Then
        Worksheets("Test").Range(E5).ClearContents
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Consider event code.  You could store the entry time on your hidden sheet following a `worksheet_change` event; and perhaps check all the relevant cells on a `worksheet_activate` event (or even `selection_change` if that doesn't fire too often).

Comment: For the moment I have the code nested within the workbook open section. It does not need to be run particularly often.